# Refactoring switch cases

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, design-patterns, refactoring

Please consider this psudo code:

```
switch (ddlPlan.SelectedValue)
{
    #region 02
       case "2":
           BL_02 bl_02 = new BL_02();
           bl_02.DeleteQues(Id, Version);
           break;
    #endregion

    #region 0503
       case "3":
           BL_03 bl_03 = new BL_03();
           bl_03.DeleteQues(Id, Version);
           break;
    #endregion

    #region 0505
       case "5":
           BL_05 bl_05 = new BL_05();
           bl_05.DeleteQues(Id, Version);
           break;
    #endregion
}
```

How I can refactor this code to remove this switch cases?

Much of my problem is how to get instance of `BLs` in appropriate way.

thanks

Comment: Do each of the `BL_??`'s shared a common base class with the `DeleteQues` method?

Comment: Thanks dear @Enigmativity.Can you please write your suggested code as answer?

Comment: Please answer my question. Without knowing how your code is written I can't give you a good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about something like this?

Put this somewhere and then make your BL classes implement it:

```
public interface IBL
{
    void DeleteQues(string id, string version); // Assuming these are strings
}
```

Then rewrite your switch statement like this:

```
IBL bl;
switch (ddlPlan.SelectedValue)
{
    case "2": bl = new BL_02(); break;
    case "3": bl = new BL_03(); break;
    case "5": bl = new BL_05(); break;
}

bl.DeleteQues(Id, Version);
```

Alternatively, you could create a `Dictionary<string, Type>` instead of using a switch:

```
Dictionary<string, Type> blTypes = new Dictionary<string, Type>
    {
       { "2", typeof(BL_02) },
       { "3", typeof(BL_03) },
       { "5", typeof(BL_05) }
    }
```

And then instead of using switch you'd just do:

```
IBL bl = (IBL)Activator.CreateInstance(blTypes[ddlPlan.SelectedValue]);  // Could check if key exists
bl.DeleteQues(Id, Version);
```

Or, if you really wanted to get fancy and make it scalable, you could use reflection to generate the name of the class you want to instantiate.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming each class is a child of `BL_Parent`, you can use reflection to dynamically instantiate the class from a string value.

```
var className = String.format("BL_{0,2}", ddlPlan.SelectedValue);

var blObj = (BL_Parent)Activator.CreateInstance(null, className);

blObj.DeleteQues(Id, Version);
```

If you only want a certain set of numbers available, you can white list them like so.

```
var whitelist = new string[] { "2", "3", "5" };

if (!whitelist.Contains(ddlPlan.SelectedValue))
    // handle exception
```

You can find more information about `Activator.CreateInstance()` **[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4.aspx)**.

Also, I suggest you re-factor your class structures, because judging by the naming conventions, there are better ways of handling data like this.