# Listbox as form selector

Tags: c#, .net

How to efficiently detect which element of Listbox was selected and switch to the corresponding form? Currently, I'm doing it like so:

```
public static Form GetForm(string name)
{
    switch (name)       //name - Selected item in listbox as string
    {
        case "Преломление Света":
            return new Light();
        case "Закон Ома":
            return new OHMsLaw();
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

It works fine , but I doubt that my solution is ok.

Comment: What do your unit test say about the function? Does it produce results you expect? If yes why you think there is something wrong with your code. If no - you should be asking different question. If you have question about [refactoring switch cases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822683/refactoring-switch-cases) - feel free to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store the Forms in a dictionary, such as:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<string, Form> _forms;

void InitDictionaries(){
    _forms = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Form>();
    _forms.TryAdd("Преломление Света", new Light()>;
    _forms.TryAdd("Закон Ома", new OHMsLaw()>;
    //...
}
```

So, when it comes to the selection, I could use:

```
public Form GetForm(string name)
{
    Form toShow;
    _forms.TryGetValue(name, out toShow);
    return show;   
}
```

This dictionary stores the form instances.

---

**Another approach** is to store the derived Forms' **type**, but if you would like to store existing ones its not a good solution, since it creates new instances.

```
ConcurrentDictionary<string, Type> _forms;
```

You would add the type this way:

```
_forms.TryAdd("Закон Ома", typeof(OHMsLaw));
```

You would use this way:

```
public Form GetForm(string name)
{
    Type type;
    _forms.TryGetValue(name, out type);
    if (type != null)
        return Activator.CreateInstance(type) as Form;

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Not sure how this is different from existing answers on "refactoring switch" like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822683/refactoring-switch-cases... Also not clear if refactoring switch statement is the problem OP is trying to solve here.

Comment: The second solution is just perfect!
Also, it probably can't be `return Activator.CreateInstance(type);` it should be something like: `return Activator.CreateInstance(type) as Form;`

Comment: You are right, I forgot to add the casting, since I was writing the source directly here, to SO. I'm correcting it, thanks for pointing it out.